# How to set the correct stroke width for a svg rect

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg, stroke

I have this svg animation with js and css. Check the link for full animation http://jsfiddle.net/kpk1l/bL90srby/

- How can I have the same stroke width for left/right like top?

```css
.fil0 {fill:#00ACEC;}
.fil1 {fill:#929292;}
.fil2 {fill:#FEFEFE;}
.str0 {stroke:#00ACEC;stroke-width:50px;}
.fil3 {fill:none}
 
html, body {
  height: 100%; 
}
.wrapper {
  display:-webkit-box;
  display:-ms-flexbox;
  display:flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  height:100%;
}

svg {
  max-width: 80%;
  width: 100%; 
}   

#frame-outline {
  stroke-dasharray: 8400;
  stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
  stroke-width: 30px;
  animation: 1s frame-outline 1 forwards;
}
@keyframes frame-outline {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 8000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}


#fadeChen {
  display: none
}
.chen {
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  animation: main 1s forwards, second 1s forwards ;
  animation-delay:0s;
}

@keyframes main {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
  
  100% {
     transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
@keyframes second {
  from {
    width:100%;
  }
  to {
    width:36%;
  }
}

#fadeText {
  display: none
}

.fade-in {
 opacity: 1;
 animation-name: fadeInOpacity;
 animation-iteration-count: 1;
 animation-timing-function: ease-in;
 animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

@keyframes fadeInOpacity {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 1;
 }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Creator: CorelDRAW X6 -->
<div class="wrapper">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" width="3000px" height="780px" version="1.1" style="shape-rendering:geometricPrecision; text-rendering:geometricPrecision; image-rendering:optimizeQuality; fill-rule:evenodd; clip-rule:evenodd"
viewBox="0 0 3000 780"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 
 
 <g id="Layer_x0020_1">
  <metadata id="CorelCorpID_0Corel-Layer"/>
  
  <rect id="fadeChen" class="fil0" width="1061" height="780"> 
  
  </rect>
  
  <g id="fadeText">
  <path id="o" class="fil1" d="M1411 641c148,0 248,-117 248,-251l0 -1c0,-134 -99,-250 -247,-250 -148,0 -248,117 -248,251l0 1c0,134 99,250 247,250zm1 -51c-111,0 -191,-90 -191,-200l0 -1c0,-110 79,-199 190,-199 111,0 191,90 191,200l0 1c0,110 -79,199 -190,199z"/>
   <polygon id="n2" class="fil1" points="1871,304 2129,633 2173,633 2173,147 2120,147 2120,536 1871,220 "/>
   <polygon id="n1" class="fil1" points="1762,633 1816,633 1816,626 1816,235 1816,147 1814,147 1762,147 "/>
   <polygon id="i" class="fil1" points="2276,633 2331,633 2331,147 2276,147 "/>
   <polygon id="k2" class="fil1" points="2543,447 2592,398 2778,633 2847,633 2630,359 2838,147 2767,147 2543,380 "/>
   <polygon id="k1" class="fil1" points="2434,633 2489,633 2489,502 2489,437 2489,147 2434,147 "/>
   <path id="b" class="fil2" d="M103 633l216 0c106,0 176,-49 176,-132l0 -1c0,-67 -46,-100 -104,-117 38,-17 77,-49 77,-112l0 -1c0,-31 -11,-57 -31,-78 -28,-27 -71,-43 -127,-43l-207 0 0 485zm309 -356c0,57 -46,87 -112,87l-144 0 0 -167 148 0c69,0 108,31 108,79l0 1zm27 218l0 1c0,54 -46,87 -119,87l-163 0 0 -171 153 0c85,0 129,31 129,83z"/>
   <polygon id="e2" class="fil2" points="604,633 958,633 958,583 659,583 659,413 923,413 923,363 604,363 "/>
   <polygon id="e1" class="fil2" points="604,197 955,197 955,147 604,147 "/>
 </g>

 <rect id="frame-outline" class="fil3 str0" width="3000" height="780"/>
 </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

I made it only with css first but I had problem with animation-delay so I used js. 
* Can you help me optimizing and correcting it?

You have any solution to make it appear on IE (for example now the stroke animation stop on IE and I want it to skip animation and directly show the logo - only for IE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem regarding the stroke width is actually not related to the `stroke-width` at all. Your viewport is just to small and some parts of the border are cut of.

If you make the SVG a little wider (or the border use a smaller width) everything is fine. The below exampole changed the `viewBox` as follows:

```
viewBox="-50 0 3100 780"
```

```css
.fil0 {fill:#00ACEC;}
.fil1 {fill:#929292;}
.fil2 {fill:#FEFEFE;}
.str0 {stroke:#00ACEC;stroke-width:50px;}
.fil3 {fill:none}
 
html, body {
  height: 100%; 
}
.wrapper {
  display:-webkit-box;
  display:-ms-flexbox;
  display:flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  height:100%;
}

svg {
  max-width: 80%;
  width: 100%; 
}   

#frame-outline {
  stroke-dasharray: 8400;
  stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
  stroke-width: 30px;
  animation: 1s frame-outline 1 forwards;
}
@keyframes frame-outline {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 8000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}


#fadeChen {
  display: none
}
.chen {
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  animation: main 1s forwards, second 1s forwards ;
  animation-delay:0s;
}

@keyframes main {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
  
  100% {
     transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
@keyframes second {
  from {
    width:100%;
  }
  to {
    width:36%;
  }
}

#fadeText {
  display: none
}

.fade-in {
 opacity: 1;
 animation-name: fadeInOpacity;
 animation-iteration-count: 1;
 animation-timing-function: ease-in;
 animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

@keyframes fadeInOpacity {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 1;
 }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Creator: CorelDRAW X6 -->
<div class="wrapper">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" width="3000px" height="780px" version="1.1" style="shape-rendering:geometricPrecision; text-rendering:geometricPrecision; image-rendering:optimizeQuality; fill-rule:evenodd; clip-rule:evenodd"
viewBox="-50 0 3100 780"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 
 
 <g id="Layer_x0020_1">
  <metadata id="CorelCorpID_0Corel-Layer"/>
  
  <rect id="fadeChen" class="fil0" width="1061" height="780"> 
  
  </rect>
  
  <g id="fadeText">
  <path id="o" class="fil1" d="M1411 641c148,0 248,-117 248,-251l0 -1c0,-134 -99,-250 -247,-250 -148,0 -248,117 -248,251l0 1c0,134 99,250 247,250zm1 -51c-111,0 -191,-90 -191,-200l0 -1c0,-110 79,-199 190,-199 111,0 191,90 191,200l0 1c0,110 -79,199 -190,199z"/>
   <polygon id="n2" class="fil1" points="1871,304 2129,633 2173,633 2173,147 2120,147 2120,536 1871,220 "/>
   <polygon id="n1" class="fil1" points="1762,633 1816,633 1816,626 1816,235 1816,147 1814,147 1762,147 "/>
   <polygon id="i" class="fil1" points="2276,633 2331,633 2331,147 2276,147 "/>
   <polygon id="k2" class="fil1" points="2543,447 2592,398 2778,633 2847,633 2630,359 2838,147 2767,147 2543,380 "/>
   <polygon id="k1" class="fil1" points="2434,633 2489,633 2489,502 2489,437 2489,147 2434,147 "/>
   <path id="b" class="fil2" d="M103 633l216 0c106,0 176,-49 176,-132l0 -1c0,-67 -46,-100 -104,-117 38,-17 77,-49 77,-112l0 -1c0,-31 -11,-57 -31,-78 -28,-27 -71,-43 -127,-43l-207 0 0 485zm309 -356c0,57 -46,87 -112,87l-144 0 0 -167 148 0c69,0 108,31 108,79l0 1zm27 218l0 1c0,54 -46,87 -119,87l-163 0 0 -171 153 0c85,0 129,31 129,83z"/>
   <polygon id="e2" class="fil2" points="604,633 958,633 958,583 659,583 659,413 923,413 923,363 604,363 "/>
   <polygon id="e1" class="fil2" points="604,197 955,197 955,147 604,147 "/>
 </g>

 <rect id="frame-outline" class="fil3 str0" width="3000" height="780"/>
 </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you check the full animation in link and tell me if all the code is good and if I have to correct something for other browsers for example?

Comment: And for IE can I make something like  .. <if IE ..show.... i don't know exactly how. Just a solution for IE to not have the animation freeze :|

Comment: If your code is working and you're looking for improvements or suggestions, maybe https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is the better place. Regarding IE: Seems to me, this is just a debugging task. Open the dev tools and work your way through the error messages. Currently you are using some APIs that are not supported by IE (I see at least an error concerning `classList`).

Comment: Ok. I will check that site. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IE does not support CSS animation of SVG elements.  Edge **does** support it, but it insists that all CSS values have units.

So you'll need to change the lines like this:

```
stroke-dasharray: 8400;
```

to this:

```
stroke-dasharray: 8400px;
```

```css
.fil0 {fill:#00ACEC;}
.fil1 {fill:#929292;}
.fil2 {fill:#FEFEFE;}
.str0 {stroke:#00ACEC;stroke-width:50px;}
.fil3 {fill:none}
 
html, body {
  height: 100%; 
}
.wrapper {
  display:-webkit-box;
  display:-ms-flexbox;
  display:flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  height:100%;
}

svg {
  max-width: 80%;
  width: 100%; 
}   

#frame-outline {
  stroke-dasharray: 8400px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 2000px;
  stroke-width: 30px;
  animation: 1s frame-outline 1 forwards;
}
@keyframes frame-outline {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 8000px;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
  }
}


#fadeChen {
  display: none
}
.chen {
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  animation: main 1s forwards, second 1s forwards ;
  animation-delay:0s;
}

@keyframes main {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
  
  100% {
     transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
@keyframes second {
  from {
    width:100%;
  }
  to {
    width:36%;
  }
}

#fadeText {
  display: none
}

.fade-in {
 opacity: 1;
 animation-name: fadeInOpacity;
 animation-iteration-count: 1;
 animation-timing-function: ease-in;
 animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

@keyframes fadeInOpacity {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 1;
 }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Creator: CorelDRAW X6 -->
<div class="wrapper">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" width="3000px" height="780px" version="1.1" style="shape-rendering:geometricPrecision; text-rendering:geometricPrecision; image-rendering:optimizeQuality; fill-rule:evenodd; clip-rule:evenodd"
viewBox="-50 0 3100 780"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 
 
 <g id="Layer_x0020_1">
  <metadata id="CorelCorpID_0Corel-Layer"/>
  
  <rect id="fadeChen" class="fil0" width="1061" height="780"> 
  
  </rect>
  
  <g id="fadeText">
  <path id="o" class="fil1" d="M1411 641c148,0 248,-117 248,-251l0 -1c0,-134 -99,-250 -247,-250 -148,0 -248,117 -248,251l0 1c0,134 99,250 247,250zm1 -51c-111,0 -191,-90 -191,-200l0 -1c0,-110 79,-199 190,-199 111,0 191,90 191,200l0 1c0,110 -79,199 -190,199z"/>
   <polygon id="n2" class="fil1" points="1871,304 2129,633 2173,633 2173,147 2120,147 2120,536 1871,220 "/>
   <polygon id="n1" class="fil1" points="1762,633 1816,633 1816,626 1816,235 1816,147 1814,147 1762,147 "/>
   <polygon id="i" class="fil1" points="2276,633 2331,633 2331,147 2276,147 "/>
   <polygon id="k2" class="fil1" points="2543,447 2592,398 2778,633 2847,633 2630,359 2838,147 2767,147 2543,380 "/>
   <polygon id="k1" class="fil1" points="2434,633 2489,633 2489,502 2489,437 2489,147 2434,147 "/>
   <path id="b" class="fil2" d="M103 633l216 0c106,0 176,-49 176,-132l0 -1c0,-67 -46,-100 -104,-117 38,-17 77,-49 77,-112l0 -1c0,-31 -11,-57 -31,-78 -28,-27 -71,-43 -127,-43l-207 0 0 485zm309 -356c0,57 -46,87 -112,87l-144 0 0 -167 148 0c69,0 108,31 108,79l0 1zm27 218l0 1c0,54 -46,87 -119,87l-163 0 0 -171 153 0c85,0 129,31 129,83z"/>
   <polygon id="e2" class="fil2" points="604,633 958,633 958,583 659,583 659,413 923,413 923,363 604,363 "/>
   <polygon id="e1" class="fil2" points="604,197 955,197 955,147 604,147 "/>
 </g>

 <rect id="frame-outline" class="fil3 str0" width="3000" height="780"/>
 </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: ok. thanks. in the end I changed the value of stroke-dashoffset: 2000px; to 800 to not have that stop in IE